# Onde encontrar a biblioteca Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, windows-mobile

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação no Smart Device para Windows Mobile 6 no Visual Studio 2008 C#.

Nesta aplicação preciso utilizar as funções do objeto `CameraCaptureDialog`, pois, o objetivo principal do mesmo é capturar fotos através da câmera do coletor. Mas, eu não estou conseguindo encontrar a biblioteca `Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Forms`, neste caminho só encontro a `Microsoft.WindowsMobile.DirectX`.

Estou com o SDK do Windows Mobile 6 Professional instalado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez seu problema só colocar uma referência ao *assembly* no projeto. Instruções básicas para o Visual Studio:

- Abra o Solution Explorer.
- Com o botão direito do *mouse* clique no seu projeto e escolha `Add Reference...`
- Na aba `.NET` procure pelo *assembly* deseja usar e clique em `OK`.

Mas se quer a localização mesmo tente ver se tem alguma coisa em `\Program Files\Windows Mobile 6 SDK\Managed Libraries\` ou algum lugar por perto. Caso não ache, use alguma forma de busca do sistema operacional ou software externo para localizá-la.

Se você não tem a DLL pode baixar em um *site* especializado como o [DLLCheck](http://www.dllcheck.com/source/Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Forms.dll.html) ou [FixErrorKit](http://www.fixerrorkit.com/fix-error/fix-Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Forms.dll-error.html) (também tem informações importantes para ajudar resolver o real problema). Mas lembre-se que a falta dela provavelmente indica que você tem outros problemas.

Comment: Realmente eu estava sem a dll e consegui encontrar no site DLLCheck