# GeoCoordinate não contém um definição para GetDistanceTo

Tags: c#, geolocalização

Estou tentando fazer um algoritmo que calcula a distancia entre dois pontos a partir de suas coordenadas (Latitude e Longitude), nas minhas pesquisas acabei me deparando com GeoCoordinate (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.device.location.geocoordinate?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8). Contudo não estou conseguindo utilizar a função `GetDistanceTo`.

Error :

> "GeoCordinate" não contém uma definição para "GetDistanceTo" e não foi
>   possível encontrar nenhum método de extensão "GetDistanceTo" que
>   aceite um primeiro argumento do tipo "GeoCoordinate"

Código c#:

```
using Nest;
using System;

namespace Gps
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double long1 = -38.527498;
            double lat1 = -3.734876;
            double long2 = -38.529240;
            double lat2 = -3.743198;

            var locA = new GeoCoordinate(lat1, long1);
            var locB = new GeoCoordinate(lat2, long2);

            double distance = locA.GetDistanceTo(locB);
        }
    }
}
```

Acho que deve ser besteira, mas já perdi um bom tempo tentando resolver este problema, agradeço desde já caso alguém possa me ajudar apontando a onde esta o erro.

Comment: O que é esse `Nest`? O fato de não ter colocado `using System.Device.Location` pode ser a razão do erro. E pode estar confundindo com esse `Nest`.

Comment: @Maniero adicionar o Nest foi uma recomendação do próprio Visual Studio. Tentei remover ele e adicionar o using System.Device.Location, como você aconselhou, mas não estou conseguindo adicionar referencia ao System.Device.Location. Error : "Device" não existe no namespace System.

Comment: É quase certo que eu acertei o problema então. Agora você precisa resolver a questão de adicionar a referência que acho que já foi respondido em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47598/101 ou https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47310/101 ou https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40761/101 ou outras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você criou uma solução console que utiliza o .NET Core, que o impede de adicionar referências a assemblies pois o objetivo desse tipo de aplicação é ser compatível com o Mono.

Quando tenta utilizar o tipo `GeoCoordinate` nesse tipo de aplicação o IntelliSense informa o erro e sugere que instale o pacote `Nest` que possui uma versão incompleta da classe `GeoCoordinate`.

Para utilizar a classe `GeoCoordinate` primeiro você tem que criar o projeto do tipo correto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O correto é o projeto em que está escrito `Console App(.NET Framework)`

Criado esse projeto adicione a referência ao Assembly `System.Device`, que é onde se encontra o Namespace `System.Device.Location`, e faça a referencia ao namespace `System.Device.Location` em seu código.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então seu código funcionará sem problemas.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Device.Location;


namespace Gps
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double long1 = -38.527498;
            double lat1 = -3.734876;
            double long2 = -38.529240;
            double lat2 = -3.743198;

            var locA = new GeoCoordinate(lat1, long1);
            var locB = new GeoCoordinate(lat2, long2);

            double distance = locA.GetDistanceTo(locB);
            Console.WriteLine("A distancia é:" + distance);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você poderia citar fontes?

Comment: @MauryDeveloper: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server aqui explica a diferença e os casos de uso de aplicações .NET Core e .NET Framework, a explanação é aplicada a contextos de servidores mas não é difícil extender o conhecimento para aplicações locais de console.

Comment: Bom garoto merece +1. Eu entendi tudo.

Comment: @MauryDeveloper você viu, dá entender, foi minha impressão, que o .NET Core é para ser usado de forma similar ao NodeJS.